# Keep running node script after exit code 1

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have a script in NodeJS that pulls data from external API's and inserts data into mongodb, running every minute. I am running the script with `forever` module so that it attempts to restart if there's an error.

I started the script before I went to bed, and when I woke up in the morning the console was paused at this error:

> D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\cryptoDataApp\scripts\tickers.js:305
>           var currencyPairs = Object.keys(pairsObj);
>                                      ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Request._callback (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\cryptoDataApp\scripts\tickers.js:305:40)
>       at Request.self.callback (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\cryptoDataApp\node_modules\request\request.js:123:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\cryptoDataApp\node_modules\request\request.js:893:14)
>       at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (D:\Dropbox (Personal)\coding\cryptoDataApp\node_modules\request\request.js:844:12)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1

This error didn't happen until after the script ran a few hundred times.

It was referring to this code:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const apiUrl = 'https://api.liqui.io/api/3/info'
  request.get({
      url: apiUrl,
      timeout: 5000
    },
    function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, 'liqui ticker update error')
        reject(err, 'liqui ticker update error')
      }
      if (!err) {

        body = JSON.parse(body)
        var pairsObj = body.pairs
        var currencyPairs = Object.keys(pairsObj); //pairsObj undefined or null here

        resolve(currencyPairs)
      }
    }
  )
})
```

I'm assuming the issue is that the API responded with something other than an error or the expected object.

Two questions:

1. Instead of checking `if (!err)` should I be checking to see if the `body` is the expected object? For example `if (body.pairs !== undefined)`
2. How can I prevent the script from exiting on these types of errors with exit code 1? The script pulls data from 7 API's using 7 different functions, so I would prefer that the specific function is exited and the rest continue to execute.

So:

```js
function fn60sec() {
  //get all ticker data
  getTickers.poloniex()
  getTickers.gdax()
  getTickers.bitfinex()
  getTickers.bitstamp()
  getTickers.bittrex()
  getTickers.liqui() //if this function exits, go on with the others
  getTickers.btce()
}

fn60sec();
setInterval(fn60sec, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I think ``try catch`` method help you.

Comment: and ``body.hasOwnProperty("pairs")`` This method may help you to check expected property in ``body`` object